# Is there a set which cannot be proven to be finite or infinite

Tags: set-theory

Is there a set which cannot be proven to be finite or infinite? The set must be not be proven to be infinite of any cardinality.

I am a novice at set theory regarding these topics, so if this is something that I can solve for myself if I study the right topics, pointing out the topics will be very helpful to me.

Comment: The set of all zeros (excluding trivial zeros) of the Riemann zeta function with real part $\neq 1/2$ ?

Comment: Clarify... "**cannot** be proven" or "*has not yet been* proven."  There is a very fine distinction between these two statements.

Comment: I am not sure if those answer *exactly* your question, but the answers can modified ever so slightly by replacing "finite" with "the set of reals", or whatever.

Comment: I mean cannot be proven, not has not yet been proven.

Comment: Proofs don't exist in vacuum. What is your base theory? ZFC? ZF? ZFC+large cardinals? ZFC+forcing axioms? NF?

Comment: I am a novice, and will accept any base theory. I would like something more tangible then {∣≤ and  is consistent}, though. That is, I would like to confirm that it does have at least some elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the set of all primes $p$ such that $p+2$ is also prime. Then, proving that this set is infinite or finite means proving or disproving, respectively, the Twin Prime Conjecture.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I would like a set that can be formally proved to be unprovable as finite or infinite, but this is still encouraging. There may be a set that matches what I am looking for.

Comment: Reflecting further, I am willing to go along with this answer. Thank you very much.